# Dynamic Visibility not working during execution of stored procedure

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help with my code. Upon clicking the trigger to execute the Stored Procedure, I want to show my Label to show its still loading. Although the Execution of Stored Procedure was successful, but still the label does not show and sometimes I ended up having this error:

> 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected

Please help. And here are my codes

```
private void btnSync_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            loadingLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            context.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
            grdHistory.ItemsSource = context.SP_PushLogsToHQ().ToList();
            loadingLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            MessageBox.Show("User's Time Logs Updated.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

'ContextSwitchDeadlock' is just a warning from VS debug for thing with long time to process.
You can go to Debug > Exceptions in the menu and expand the "Managed Debugging Assistants" and disable it.